# Rails - Render External Url in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model which has links from a **scraper** /crawler. Currently i am using link_to to link to them directly. for eg.

```
<%= link_to chapter.chapter_number, extlink(chapter.chapter_url) %>
```

What i would like to do is to have a tool-bar at the top and render all the other page below it.

The only option that i know might work is i-frames but i am averse to going that way. Is there any other method i can use to render the pages? (I don't know if this will factor into the solution but I plan to do some page caching once i work how to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the source code of a website like following:

```
require 'open-uri'
source = open("http://google.com").read
```

Now you can do following at your view:

```
<%= source.html_safe %>
```

Though I don't think you should be doing this.